# Why does my kitten's urine clean my carpet?

Tags: cleaning, carpet

I have an old house with very old wall to wall carpets. The carpet by the front door is just awful, and I have been trying to clean it for a while, with poor results.

Recently, however, my kitten, who is not yet house broken, peed on a spot on the carpet, and it was immediately cleaned of all the old dirt (the pee needed cleaning up, of course)!

Since I have no plan to make the kitten pee everywhere, does anyone know exactly what in the pee cleaned the carpet, and maybe how to duplicate the effect in a more sanitary way?

Comment: the one component that comes to mind is ammonia

Comment: I think it is time to replace the carpeting in the house.

Comment: I don't disagree. Saving up for it.

Comment: We have all been there, when peeing on the floor makes it look better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Urine (human and animal) contains ammonia, paricularly if it's left for a while, e.g. if you didn't notice it at first.  Ammonia is [used in carpet-cleaning products](http://www.drysolutions.com/carpet-cleaning-101-using-ammonia-to-clean-your-carpet/).  In fact it's been used for stain-removal since [Roman times](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/from-gunpowder-to-teeth-whitener-the-science-behind-historic-uses-of-urine-442390/).

You might want to track down an ammonia-based carpet cleaner, but use it when you can open all the windows and sit outside for a bit afterwards.